# Lydia seems to have become invulnerable

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

A while ago I used the enable/disable command on Lydia to level her up to my current level, as I wanted to keep using her throughout the game. However, and I'm not sure if it happened after that leveling or after the Thalmor Embassy quest, she seems to have become almost invulnerable. No matter what hits her, her health bar drops almost nothing.

She actually managed to defeat [Orchendor](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Orchendor) on her own, as well as a randomly-encountered dragon, without effort and without any intervention from me.

Is there any way to detect, through console commands, what is something wrong with her, such as excessively high health regen or armor rating? And if so, how can I get her back to normal? I don't complain about having a powerful follower, but having a too powerful one, well, makes the game a bit boring.

Thanks!

Comment: change follower? :) Maybe not desired, but its definately an option as last resort.

Comment: Did you set her up against Alduin as well? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target Lydia in the console, then use `getav x` where x is an [actor value indice](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes5Mod:Actor_Value_Indices) like **health** or **CombatHealthRegenMult**. Try using `resurrect` on her, it should reset her stats to what is appropriate.

Comment: Respawn does not seem to be recognised as a command, so I actually trying killing her and using resurrect. Funny thing, not even the kill command would work, she just fell to her knees and got up almost immediately. I went for the enable/disable trick again, and it seems to have worked, even though her stats (like health or regen) did not change, she can now feel some pain :) Thanks!

Comment: Derp, resurrect is what I meant to type.

Comment: Forgot what I said, it's happening again, and this time the enable/disable trick is not working. I'll have to go with another follower it seems. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That's really strange, sounds like you have an underlying problem. Are you running any mods that would affect NPCs like that?

Comment: Nothing at all, I have a clean install without any mods whatsoever. Don't worry, now she is back OK again, let's hope she stays this way.